# Можно ли отключить в Excel 2016 обращение к левым сайтам microsoft?

Tags: excel, office

Постоянно вылетает такая хрень куда у меня доступа нету... Даже если открыть пустой Excel.
[image: E]

Приходится многократно ее отменить, прежде чем от меня отстанут...

Comment: Записать в hosts: **url** 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: А отключать-то пробовали - [disable online template search](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/how-to-disable-online-template-search-in-office/3e6cf9dc-826c-4b1e-875b-3224cbdb7d38) ?

Comment: @Daemon-5 Да я даже не знал как загуглить эту хрень. Вроде, ваше предложение помогло.